# Setting spaces (with titlespacing) and fonts

Tags: line-spacing

I am struggling with the spaces and font. 
Firstly, how can I set the spaces like below? (All paragraphs will be have 1.5 line spacing too)
Secondly, how can I set all fonts as Times New Roman and 12pt?

[image: Sample]

**1. CHAPTER**

(1.5 line spacing)

**1.1. Section**

(1.5 line spacing)

Paragraph

(2 line spacing)

**1.2. Section**

(1.5 line spacing)

Paragraph

(2 line spacing)

**1.2.1. Subsection**

(1.5 line spacing)

Paragraph

(2 line spacing)

**1.2.1.1. Subsubsection**

(1.5 line spacing)

Paragraph

(2 line spacing)

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}  





%****************************************
% CHAPTERS
% Chapter titles
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Remove (Chapter X).
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

% Spaces
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\normalsize}

\titlespacing*{\section}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}{\thesection.}{1em}{\normalsize}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{\normalsize}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{\normalsize}


% BEGIN
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} %Paragraph intend


% Chapter 1
\chapter{CHAPTER}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
%........................................

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Part 1: 1.5 line spacing

Depending on what exactly you mean by `1.5 line spacing`, there are different solutions. Don’t use `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`.

1. If you want `12pt` text on a `1.5*12 = 18pt` [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading), then you can use

   ```
   \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
   ```

   or even better

   ```
   \usepackage[onehalfspacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
   ```
2. If you want the line spacing to be `1.5` times that of the single line spacing, then you can use

   ```
   \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
   \setstretch{1.5}
   ```
3. If you want your line-spacing calculation to be based on that of Microsoft Word, then you should know that in MS Word “single line spacing” depends on the typeface/font.

   For Times New Roman, the single line spacing is `2048` units of text on `2355` units of leading. In TeX, a `12pt` report has `12pt` text on `14.5pt` leading.

   So, in order to achieve `1.5 line spacing as MS Word`, you need a stretch value of `(1.5*2355/2048)/(14.5/12) = 1.427465`:

   ```
   \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
   \setstretch{1.427465}
   ```

## Part 2: Times New Roman typeface

Use [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/termes), a Times New Roman clone:

```
% https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

If you do so, then don’t use `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

**Added**: Let me know if you know which one is TeX Gyre Termes and which one is Times New Roman.

[image: TeX Gyre Termes vs Times New Roman]

Again, if your goal is to mimic MS Word, then you need to slightly scale up the typeface as well as the line spacing stretch by a factor of `72.27/72 = 1.00375`. This is because TeX’s `1pt` is `1/72.27` inches, while MS Word’s `1pt` is `1/72` inches.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.432818}% <-- 1.00375*1.427465
...
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% <-- Load hyperref last
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

**Additional notes**: You generally want your `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to be the last package loading in your preamble. And since `hyperref` is loaded, you don’t need `\usepackage{url}` any more.

## Part 3: Modify the vertical spaces and put them together

**Added**: Please at least read Section 9.2 of the [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual. Your code is not suitable for your desired format.

To modify the vertical space around headings in a consistent way, I propose to create <del>a macro `\myvspace`</del> two macros `\myonehalfvspace` and `\mytwovspace`. Depending on what exactly you mean by `1.5 line spacing`, the value you put in `\newcommand*{\myonehalfvspace}{...}` can be any one of `18pt`, `21.75pt`, `20.698242pt` or `20.775861pt`. Same goes for `\mytwovspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% Page settings
\usepackage[
    tmargin=4cm,% top margin, your ``4cm'' request
    %bmargin=?,% bottom margin
    %lmargin=?,% left margin
    %rmargin=?% right margin
  ]{geometry}
% Font and line spacing settings
\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.432818}% <-- 1.00375*1.427465
% Customize headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\myonehalfvspace}{20.775861pt}% <-- Define a macro \myonehalfvspace
\newcommand*{\mytwovspace}{27.701147pt}% <-- Define a macro \mytwovspace
% Chapter heading
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{\myonehalfvspace plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% Section heading
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{1cm}{\mytwovspace plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% Paragraph indent
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
% Dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{CHAPTER}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: result]

Do you really want your headings to be at the same size? Note where `4cm` and `1cm` appear in the code.

Comment: Hi Ruixi. Thank you for detailed answer. I am a very new user on Latex, your kindless is very important for me. I edited my post (added referance image and changed line spacing after paragraphs). The main theme is prepared according to Microsoft Word. So the spaces and fonts mentioned must be set according to Microsoft Word. So, your last commands need to change?

Comment: Yes, headings are at the same size.

Comment: @volkanyazici It’s rather pointless using TeX if you intended to use it as MS Word. The fact that you’re to obey these ridiculously complicated rules hints that the rule makers know nothing about typography: (a) Are you aware that the license of Monotype’s Times New Roman is *proprietary*? Do you understand the **legal implications** of simply *using* Times New Roman? In your pic: (b) First two `1.5 line space` braces aren’t even the same size! (c) Body text is too crowded to be `1.5 line space`. (d) Inconsistent vertical spaces: From bottom-line to top-line? Or from baseline to baseline?

Comment: @volkanyazici I’ve added a picture showing the fonts. Let me know if you know which one is TeX Gyre Termes and which one is Times New Roman. I’ve also accommodated your new requests about `4cm`, `1cm` and `2 line space`. You can see the output as well. Please at least read the [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual.

Comment: Normally a sample template should to be created by rule makers. But not created. So I am trying to create a template with using the thesis writing guide. Thank you for helpful suggestions and information. I tested the codes, they are working. Best wishes.

Comment: @volkanyazici You’re welcome! If you’re satisfied with my answer, perhaps you can accept it?

Comment: yes i did already upvote as an answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @volkanyazici Thank you for the upvote. :) But I was referring to the tick mark under the upvote, if you wish to accept my answer.

Comment: sorry, i think it is ok now (: