# Changing line spacing issue

Tags: line-spacing

I am using a university template, according to my reviewer my line spacing of paragraph is not 1.5. So while trying to change I found this in cls file.

```
\def\setstretch#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}}
```

As I am new to latex so I don't know what it does but comments above warn about changing it as it may have effect on footnotes, heading, titles etc. I do not know where from #1 is coming looks like a parameter to me.

Someone told me to add linespacing in each chapter to avoid any issues with tables, margins etc. here is the class section which I think define all spacing etc. I also found a separate file for setspace.

```
%    ***************************************
%    *     SINGLESPACE ANd DOUBLESPACE     *
%    ***************************************     


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% LaTeX Document style option "doublespace"
% -- usage:  \documentstyle[...,doublespace,...]{...}
%
% This style option produces a double-spaced document by redefining
% the LaTeX parameter \baselinestretch to 2.
%
% It also fixes a number of problems with standard LaTeX, as follows:
%
% 1. A new environment "singlespace" is provided, within which single
%    spacing will apply.
%    JFL - changed so that it works in regular text and so that vertical
%    space is before and after is correctly computed
% 2. Double spacing is turned off within footnotes and floats (figures
%    and tables).
% 3. Proper double spacing happens below tabular environments and in other
%    places where LaTeX uses a strut.
% 4. Slightly more space is inserted before footnotes.
% 5. JFL - fixes spacing before and after displayed math
%
% Note: This version sets a baselinestretch of 2. If this is too much,
%    put  \setstretch{1.7}  (or some appropriate value) before the
%    \begin{document} command. To print the document with single spacing
%    again, without removing "singlespace" environments, just put a
%    \setstretch{1} at the top of the document.
%
% PLEASE REPORT ANY BUGS
%
%
% Known bugs:
%    . It might be nice if spacing before the footnote rule (\footins)
%      were provided in a tidier way.
%    . Increasing struts may possibly cause some other obscure part of
%      formatting to fall over.
%    . \begin{singlespace}\begin{quote} produces the wrong spacing before
%      the quote (extra glue is inserted).
%    . shouldn't @setsize stretch parskip as well?
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%---Set up double spacing

%\def\baselinestretch{1}


%---New command "\setstretch" (slightly more mnemonic... and easier to type)

\def\setstretch#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}}

%---Stretch the baseline BEFORE calculating the strut size. This improves
%   spacing below tabular environments etc., probably...
%   Comments are welcomed.

\def\@setsize#1#2#3#4{\@nomath#1%
   \let\@currsize#1\baselineskip
   #2\baselineskip\baselinestretch\baselineskip
   \parskip\baselinestretch\parskip
   \setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule height.7\baselineskip
      depth.3\baselineskip width\z@}%
   \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip#3#4}


%---Increase the space between last line of text and footnote rule.
%   This is a very untidy way to do it!

\skip\footins 25pt plus4pt minus4pt


%---Reset baselinestretch within footnotes and floats. Originally stolen
%   from Stanford thesis style.

\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox\color@vbox\normalcolor\vbox\bgroup 
    \def\baselinestretch{1}\small\normalsize
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty 
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

% Stolen from MIT.
%
% A single spaced quote (say) is done by surrounding singlespace with quote.
%
\def\sspace{%
\vskip\parskip%
\vskip\baselineskip%
\def\baselinestretch{0.65}%
\ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
\vskip-\parskip%
\vskip-\baselineskip%
}

\def\endsspace{\par}

%  spacing, doublespace and onehalfspace all are meant to INCREASE the
%  spacing (i.e. calling onehalfspace from within doublespace will not
%  produce a graceful transition between spacings)
%
\def\spacing#1{\par%
 \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
 \ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi}

\def\endspacing{\par%
 \vskip \parskip%
 \vskip \baselineskip%
 \endgroup%
 \vskip -\parskip%
 \vskip -\baselineskip%
 \begingroup}

\def\onehalfspace{\spacing{1.5}}
\let\endonehalfspace=\endspacing

\def\dspace{\spacing{2}}
\let\dspace=\endspacing

% Fix up spacing before and after displayed math
% (arraystretch seems to do a fine job for inside LaTeX displayed math,
% since array and eqnarray seem to be affected as expected)
% Changing \baselinestretch and doing a font change also works if done here,
% but then you have to change @setsize to remove the call to @nomath)
%
\everydisplay{
   \abovedisplayskip \baselinestretch\abovedisplayskip%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
   \abovedisplayshortskip \baselinestretch\abovedisplayshortskip%
   \belowdisplayshortskip  \baselinestretch\belowdisplayshortskip}
```

SET SPACE

```
% You may freely use, modify, and/or distribute this file, without limitation. 
%%% ======================================================================
%%%  @LaTeX-style-file{
%%%     filename        = "setspace.sty",
%%%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%%%     checksum        = "11793 546 2608 21972",
%%%     docstring       = "setspace.sty is a LaTeX (2e) package.
%%%                        Comments and bug reports welcome!
%%%                        
%%%                        Solovay's checksum utility."
%%% }
%%% ======================================================================
%% FILE:   setspace.sty in SYS2.TEX.PUB.ISULATEX.STYLES
%% AUTHOR: Erica M. S. Harris
%% DATE:   April 1990
%% MOD:    March 1991
%%%
%%% Update to LaTeX (2e) :  6 Feb 1996.
%%% Description:  LaTeX Document Package "setspace"
%%%
%%% Usage:
%%%                \documentclass[...]{...}
%%%                \usepackage{setspace}
%%%
%%         Based on the doublespace option created by Stephen Page.
%%
%%         This style option provides commands and environments for doing
%%         double and  one-and-a-half spacing based on pt size.
%%
%%         Single spacing is the default.
%%
%%         Three commands, \singlespacing, \onehalfspacing, and
%%         \doublespacing, are for use in the preamble to set the overall
%%         spacing for the document.  If a different spacing is required then
%%         the \setstretch{baselinestretch} command can be used in the
%%         preamble to set the baselinestretch appropriately.  The default
%%         spacing with this style option is single spacing.
%%
%%         Three environments, singlespace, onehalfspace, and doublespace,
%%         allow the spacing to be changed within the document.  Both the
%%         onehalfspace and doublespace environments are intended to increase
%%         the spacing, so the onehalfspace environment should not be used in
%%         a double spaced document.  If an increased spacing different from
%%         one-and-a-half or double spacing is required then the spacing
%%         environment can be used.  The spacing environment takes one
%%         argument which is the larger baselinestretch to use,
%%         e.g., \begin{spacing}{2.5}.
%%
%%         \footins is adjusted the same as \parskip - appears to work. Lose
%%         stretch parts but don't consider that to be crucial
%%
%%         Removed code for altering spacing before and after displayed
%%         equations - just looked too much.
%%
%% MODS:
%%         Redefinition of \spacing and \endspacing for consistency with
%%         TeX 3.x inserted by George Greenwade.  Modification provided by
%%         Philip Ross (ROSS@UK.AC.ABDN.BIOMED) and John Byrne via INFO-TeX.
%%
%% PLEASE REPORT ANY BUGS
%%
%%   Old Documentation follows:
%%         1. A new environment "singlespace" is provided, within which single
%%            spacing will apply.
%%            JFL - changed so that it works in regular text and so that
%%            vertical space before and after is correctly computed
%%         2. Double spacing is turned off within footnotes and floats (figures
%%            and tables).
%%         3. Proper double spacing happens below tabular environments and in
%%            other places where LaTeX uses a strut.
%%         4. Slightly more space is inserted before footnotes.
%%         5. JFL - fixes spacing before and after displayed math
%%
%%
%%    mods:   Jean-Francois Lamy
%%            lamy@ai.toronto.edu
%%            lamy@utai.uucp
%%
%% POSSIBLE BUGS:
%%    . Increasing struts may possibly cause some other obscure part of
%%      formatting to fall over.
%%    . \begin{singlespace}\begin{quote} produces the wrong spacing before
%%      the quote (extra glue is inserted).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat {LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\def \filename {setspace.sty}
\def \filedate {2000/12/01}
\def \fileversion {6.7}
\ProvidesPackage {setspace}[\filedate\space\fileversion\space
  Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package]
\typeout {Package: `setspace' \fileversion\space <\filedate>}

% BP: add nodisplayskipstretch option and \setdisplayskipstretch command.

\newcommand{\displayskipstretch}{\baselinestretch}
\newcommand{\setdisplayskipstretch}[1]{\renewcommand{\displayskipstretch}{#1}}
\DeclareOption{nodisplayskipstretch}{\setdisplayskipstretch{1.0}}

% GT: add George Pearsons' suggested options.

\DeclareOption{singlespacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\singlespacing}}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{doublespacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\doublespacing}}

\ProcessOptions

% GT:  Sat 28 Sep 1996:  Widely using \newcommand, \renewcommand, and
% \newenvironment, instead of \def.

% ** Line space commands.

\newcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize
}

% GT:  Sat 28 Sep 1996:  spacing commands and environments modified to
% use \setstretch instead of \baselinestretch.
%
% GT:  Sat 28 Sep 1996:  No, I don't know understand the line spacing
% algorithms!  If someone (LaTeX team) can enlighten me as to the
% general rule, please do!  It would be very pleasant if setspace.sty
% were suited for document font sizes other than 10, 11 and 12 pt.
%
% GT:  Tue 10 Dec 1996:  Instead of fixing singlespacing to exact unity,
% allow user to redefine it (only slightly, please!) from its initial
% value of unity, in the case when a particular font is slightly larger
% or slightly smaller than its point size would indicate.  This change
% affects setspace's single spacing commands, and LaTeX's footnote and
% float environments.  The one and a half, double, and arbitrary
% spacing commands are unaltered.

\newcommand{\SetSinglespace}[1]{%
  \def\setspace@singlespace{#1}%
}

% Here's the default single line spacing value.
\SetSinglespace{1}

\newcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%  normally 1
  \vskip \baselineskip  % Correction for coming into singlespace
}

\newcommand{\onehalfspacing}{%
  \setstretch{1.25}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.25}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.213}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.241}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\doublespacing}{%
  \setstretch {1.667}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.667}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.618}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.655}%
  \fi
}

% ** Modification of the LaTeX command \@setsize.

%---Stretch the baseline BEFORE calculating the strut size. This improves
%   spacing below tabular environments etc., probably...
%   Comments are welcomed.

% GT:  Sun 29 Sep 1996:  Question:  Is this code anywhere near correct
% since this part of LaTeX (in, eg, latex.ltx) has been greatly changed?

% GT:  Sun 29 Sep 1996:  The meanings of the arguments to \@setsize
% appear to be (whatever these may signify) :
% current size; font baselineskip; ignored (!); and font size.

% GT:  Sun 29 Sep 1996:  Note that \@setsize (in latest LaTeX,
% \@setfontsize, which is called by \@setsize) seems to be the only
% place in purely modern LaTeX where \@currsize is set, and ltxguide.cls
% seems to be the only file in the LaTeX base distribution that uses it!

\def\@setsize#1#2#3#4{%
  % Modified 1993.04.07--GDG per KPC
  \@nomath#1%
  \let\@currsize#1%
  \baselineskip #2%
  \baselineskip \baselinestretch\baselineskip
  \parskip \baselinestretch\parskip
  \setbox\strutbox \hbox{%
    \vrule height.7\baselineskip
           depth.3\baselineskip
           width\z@}%
  \skip\footins \baselinestretch\skip\footins
  \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip#3#4}

% ** Float and footnote adjustments to compensate for a change in the
% ** main text's line spacing.

%---Increase the space between last line of text and footnote rule.
%\skip\footins 20pt plus4pt minus4pt

%---Reset baselinestretch within floats and footnotes.

% GT:  Tue 23 Jan 1996:  This is where the conflict with the combination
% of the color package and the figure environment used to occur.

% Floats.

% GT:  Sat 28 Sep 1996:  \@xfloat is the only place where \normalsize
% is still used in setspace.sty !

\let\latex@xfloat=\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
  \latex@xfloat #1[#2]%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
  \normalsize
}

% GT:  Wed 24 Jan 1996:  This footnote code was copied from LaTeX and
% modified rather naively.  It had to be brought up to date, not only
% because of LaTeX's new color ability, but also because ther had
% been major changes to this code in LaTeX at least as far back as
% March 1992.

% Normal, bottom of the page, footnotes.
%
% GT:  Based HEAVILY on original LaTeX (2e) code.  A standard hook would
% be MUCH preferred, so that LaTeX's footnote implementation needn't be
% copied each time it changes.
%
% GT:  The \protected@edef requires at least the December 1994 LaTeX.
% This is precisely the kind of VERSION DEPENDENCY situation that
% cannot (AFAIK) be avoided, because LaTeX (2e) LACKS appropriate
% standard hooks and/or context markers.

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{%
  \insert\footins{%
% GT:  Next line added.  Hook desired here!
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
      \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}

% Minipage footnotes.

\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \unvbox \@mpfootins
%  GT:  Next line added.  Hook desired here!
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
      \csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
       \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
   \color@endgroup}}

% ** Line space environments.

% A single spaced quote (say) is done by surrounding singlespace with quote.

\newenvironment{singlespace}{%
  \vskip \baselineskip
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}{%
  \par
}

% GT (c/o Mark Olesen), Wed 15 April 1998.

\newenvironment{singlespace*}{%
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}{%
  \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
}

%  spacing, doublespace and onehalfspace all are meant to INCREASE the
%  spacing (i.e. calling onehalfspace from within doublespace will not
%  produce a graceful transition between spacings)
%
% Next two definitions fixed for consistency with TeX 3.x

% In order to use \newenvironment, while easily using same code for
% end of each environment, the code that used to be in \endspacing has
% been moved into a new (but internal) macro, \restore@spacing.

\newcommand{\restore@spacing}{%
    \par
    \vskip \parskip
    \vskip \baselineskip
  \endgroup
  \vskip -\parskip
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}

\newenvironment{spacing}[1]{%
  \par
  \begingroup             % moved from \endspacing by PGBR 29-1-91
    \setstretch {#1}%
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}

% one and a half spacing is 1.5 x pt size
\newenvironment{onehalfspace}{%
  \begingroup
    \onehalfspacing
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}

% double spacing is 2 x pt size
\newenvironment{doublespace}{%
  \begingroup
    \doublespacing
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}

% GT:  EMSH chose to omit display math part that follows.
% She wrote (see above) that the "altered spacing before and after displayed
% equations ... just looked too much".
%
% Fix up spacing before and after displayed math
% (arraystretch seems to do a fine job for inside LaTeX displayed math,
% since array and eqnarray seem to be affected as expected).
% Changing \baselinestretch and doing a font change also works if done here,
% but then you have to change @setsize to remove the call to @nomath)
%
% GT:  The \belowdisplayskip line was mistyped; now fixed, courtesy of
% David Hull.
%
% GT:  Brett Parnell has addressed EMSH's concern by replacing
% \baselinestretch by \displayskipstretch in displays, as follows.

\everydisplay\expandafter{%
  \the\everydisplay
  \abovedisplayskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip
}

\endinput

%%% EOF.
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: You may take a look at [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442065/164314) of mine, where the requirement is also `1.5 spacing`.

Comment: now it is more confusing

Comment: I have added a picture above that shows my current line spacing, I want 1.5 line space as in MS word inside paragraph. I am not good at formatting thing. IDEs format themselves but that is for code.

Comment: My other fellows has mostly used MS Word,but i can not as it crashes too much on my system, reviewers are probably comparing document with them

Comment: Get a PDF version of a word file with the alleged line spacing, using various methods you can place a page of that PDF in the background of your document, and then adjust the line spacing to what ever it is that PDF is using. There is no single definition of what exactly is meant by **1.5 linespacing**, is it between base lines, empty space between lines....

Comment: Empty space between two lines inside paragraph

Comment: If you please examine last file setspace.sty in middle spacing are set, I don't know how it will effect whole document so please if you check